# How to get HTML "autocomplete" enabled in VS2017 like in VS2015

Tags: html, visual-studio-2017, editing

I've searched, but couldn't find simply because I have no clue how the notation is called. 
I'm a frontend developer and I'm missing a major feature from vs2015 in vs2017, when I write HTML I typed .class and it became , now this feature isn't enabled by default (or removed). Can anybody tell me how to get this feature enabled again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too quick, another developer told me to install web essentials (2017) it should be part of that. After installing no difference, but after clicking it in tools it told me it got installed now it works like a charm again.